# Cannot setup consumer group in Kafka with Python

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka and I've tried the Kafka-Python package.

I managed to setup a simple producer and consumer, which can send and receive messages. In this case the consumer is without using consumer group as below:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(queue_name, bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092')
```

However, when I started to use the group_id as below, it stops receiving any messages:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092', auto_offset_reset='earliest', group_id='my-group')
consumer.subscribe([queue_name])
```

For comparison, I've also tried the confluent-kafka-python package, where I have the following consumer code, which also doesn't work:

```
consumer = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka:9092',
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
})
consumer.subscribe([queue_name])
```

Also running `./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list` gives empty result.

Any configuration I'm missing here?

Comment: If you ever get stumped by kafka-python, try checking the logs: `import logging; logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` (or DEBUG if you're feeling adventurous).

Answer (score 0):

By default, the consumer starts consuming from the last committed offsets which is probably the last offset in your case.

The `auto.offset.reset` only applies when there are no committed offsets. As by default the consumer automatically commits offsets, it usually only applies the first time your run it (there are a few other cases but they don't matter in this example).

So to see messages flowing, you need to either start producing once your consumer is running or use a different group name to allow `auto.offset.reset` to apply.

Comment: I tried producing the message both before and after starting the consumer. But no message is visible.